# Why does the update command display the same ppa?

Tags: linux, terminal, atom-editor, ubuntu-18.04

I was installing atom on Ubuntu 18.04.1 using the command:-

```
sudo apt-get install atom
```

I stopped the installation process and now whenever I run the command:-

```
sudo apt update
```

The following is the output:-

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Whenever I try to install Atom again, I get the following output:-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 atom : Depends: gvfs-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now, whenever I try to install a package from the terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

I get some output showing: This package has no installation candidate.

For example, if I install rpm, the output is:-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package rpm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'rpm' has no installation candidate
```

All this has been happening since the day I terminated the atom installation.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it's not programming related and would be more suitable at e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux

Comment: Thank you for the information and the link.